# How to handle <a href/> and <br/> together?

Tags: html, selenium

I have a web that has a details like in the image:

[image]

Here is the HTML content:

```
<div class="tableholder">
<br>
<br>
 Open
<a href="javascript:popWin1('/ASCNA/showTemplate.do?     
 TEMPLATE_TYPE=COLLECTION&assessment_id=98026','collection');">Collection 
 Template</a>
<br>
<br>
 Open
<a href="javascript:popWin1('/ASCNA/showTemplate.do? 
TEMPLATE_TYPE=PARSING&assessment_id=98026','parsing');">Parsing 
Template</a>
<br>
<br>
Open
<a href="javascript:popWin1('/ASCNA/showTemplate.do?
TEMPLATE_TYPE=ANALYSIS&assessment_id=98026','analysis');">Analysis 
Template</a>
<br>
<br>
```

I have to validate that when I come to this page all these options are listed. I need to use assertion.

I am not sure how to combine the text `open` inside the `<br>` tag and text `collection Template` inside `<href>` and validate.

Comment: sorry, what? Those last three lines, to me anyway, are *really* unclear. Please explain **exactly** what you're trying to do

Comment: I need to Validate whether the content 'Open collection Template' is Present in this Page

Comment: ‘Open‘ is not *inside* the `<br>` tag; `<br>` tags are always self-closing. `<br>` is equivalent to `<br/>`.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm... this webpage isn't written well.  Ideally, each case of "Open" followed by a link should be in its own element (such as a `<li>`).
But, since this is what you have to work with, you'll just have to grab all the text of the `<div>` element, which will give you:

```
Open Collection Template Open Parsing Template Open Analysis Template Open Report Template Open Device List
```

Then verify that the entire text contains the text "Open" followed by some plausible link text, as many times as you expect (in this case 5).